# Proof verification: $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are not homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, connectedness

Question:

> Show $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are not homeomorphic if $n>1$.

**My Solution:**

Let $p:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ is a quotient map.

$p(\{0\})=\{0^n\}$ is a closed map.($0^n=(0,0,\dots,0)=0\times 0\times \dots\times 0$)

Now, $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ is separated, but $\mathbb{R^n}-0^n$ is connected. Let the separations are $A$ and $B$.

Let $q:A\cup B\rightarrow p(A\cup B)$ is a quotient map.

Let, $q(A\cup B)=\mathbb{R^n}-\{0^n\}$. Then $q(A\cap B)=q(\emptyset)=q(A)\cap q(B)=C$. Now $C$ is a open set. But $q(\emptyset)$ is both open and closed, then $q(\emptyset)=\emptyset$. Then $q(A)$ and $p(B)$ are separations, which contradicts that $p$ is a quotient map.

Let $q(A\cup B)=\mathbb{R^n}$. Then $p(0)\in q(A\cup B)$. Then $0\in A\cup B$. which contradicts our assumption.

Is my argument ok?

Edit:

Thanks to **Randall** for pointing out my solution is too broad. So I will be grateful if someone give a shorter solution using Connctedness (avoiding path-connectedness would be better!)

Comment: I would have accepted a one sentence proof:  given a homeo $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$, upon deletion of a point we have a homeo $h': \mathbb{R}-\{p\} \to \mathbb{R}^n-\{h(p)\}$,  a contradiction since one is path connected, the other not.  You have this up in your argument above.

Comment: @Randall how to do in one sentence? I want to use connectedness here.

Comment: I just did.  I'm assuming you've established that the domain is not path connected, the codomain is.  Both are easy arguments to make.  (And path connectedness is a little nicer than connectedness here.  If you can easily prove that $\mathbb{R}^n-\{pt\}$ is connected, then use the same argument.  They're both invariants.)

Comment: What do you mean by quotient map in your solution?  $p(0)=0^n$ is not a map at all, and it means nothing to say such a thing is a "closed map" except on the set $\{0\}$.

Comment: Quotient maps also need not enter the story.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I was saying that $p(\{0\})=\{0^n\}$ is closed

Comment: Points are closed in a Euclidean space, but I don't think that's helpful here.

Comment: @Randall I read $p: X\rightarrow Y$ is a quotient map, then $p(A)$ is either closed map or open map. So I partitioned $\mathbb{R}$ into $\{0\}$ and $A\cup B$. Now easily $p(\{0\})$ is closed map here.

Comment: @Randall then readily I just have to show $q$ is not a quotient map.

Comment: anyway, @Randall you gave the solution in comment. Can you make an answer?

Comment: @topology_001  Edited answer below to contain an argument without path connectedness (though it does use products).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume to the contrary that $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a homeomorphism and choose a point $p \in \mathbb{R}$.  Then $h$ induces another homeomorphism $h' : \mathbb{R} -\{p\} \to \mathbb{R}^n-\{h(p)\}$.  But the codomain is (path) connected while the domain is not, a contradiction.

If you want to do this using only connectivity, you need to prove that $\mathbb{R}^n- \{\mathbf{0}\}$ is connected when $n > 1$.  (The easiest way to do this is to prove it is path connected, sorry.)

You can be cheap and hide the path connected argument inside another.  Let $X = \mathbb{R}^n-\{\mathbf{0}\}$ out of laziness, and assume that $X$ is disconnected with separation $X = A \cup B$ (open, disjoint, non-empty).  Given points $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ argue that there is a path $\alpha: [0,1] \to X$ between them.  But the image of $\alpha$ must be connected, yet it contains $a$ and $b$, a contradiction.  (I feel dirty typing this out.)

**Edit:** wait, here's a potentially better idea for your needs. Do you believe that $\mathbb{R}^n-\{\mathbf{0}\}$ is homeo to $S^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R}$?  If so, then the assumption $n > 1$ shows that the latter is connected (a product of connected spaces), which is what you wanted.

Comment: thanks, the fact that a surjective map between a path-connected space and a path-disconnected space implies not-homeo is not trivial to me actually. (Sorry, I can not up-vote your answer because of my low reputation.)

Comment: No worries.  What you establish is that $h: X \to Y$ homeo and $X$ (path) connected implies $Y$ (path) connected.  Then you get what you need by contradiction.  Whether you use connectedness or path connectedness the argument structure is the same.  You could always start a new question asking for a "simple" way to prove that space minus a point is disconnected using only basic principles.

Comment: Oops, I meant space minus a point connected.